Cardinality of a set of disjoint open sub intervals of $( 0 ,1)$
Let $A$ be any collection of disjoint open subintervals of $(0 ,1)$ . Then what is maximum cardinality of $A$ ?
I know one easy way to prove its countable is that every open interval has rational points and if there are uncountably many disjoint sub intervals in $A$ , then $(0 , 1)$ has least uncountably many rational points , a contradiction .
I have two questions now
$(1)$ The above fact I am trying to prove in some other way around (if possible)
Let $ Λ $ be indexing set for $A$  i.e
$A=\{ (a_{\alpha} , b_{\alpha}) \subset (0,1) | \alpha \in Λ   \}   $
Then the set $\{ a_{\alpha } ,  \alpha \in Λ \} $ is a discrete set (?)
Let $x_1=\inf \{ a_{\alpha} | \alpha \in Λ \}     $  So $x_1=a_m $ for some $m \in Λ$
Again $a_{\alpha} > b_m >a_m \forall \alpha \in Λ\setminus m  $
Thus let $x_2=\inf \{ a_{\alpha} | \alpha \in Λ \setminus m \}      $
In this way ,all left end points of the subintervals can be put into one one correspondence with $ℕ$ , so $A$ must be at most countable ..
Can you help me fill up the minute details here which I am obviously missing ?
$(2)$ After  a little analysing , I have the feeling that $A$  can be at most finite and not countably infinite .
Because  the set $\{ a_{\alpha } ,  \alpha \in Λ \} $ is a bounded infinite subset of $ℝ$ and so must have a limit point in $(0 ,1)$ Then we can't get a family of disjoint open sub intervals because the end points are getting arbitrarily close.
Is this true what I am thinking ?
Please help me formalise or write a proper full proof or even show counter examples , if possible . Thanks

Its easy to see that this is the same as supremum over sizes of all families of disjoint non-empty open subsets of $(0, 1)$. This is known as cellularity of a space, and it coincides with density and weight for metric spaces. That is, countable cellularity, separable and second countable all coincide for metric spaces. The answer for $(0, 1)$ is of course $\aleph_0$

Also note that in general, maximum of cardinalities need not exist.

separable means having countable dense subset but what is weight of a metric space ?

Cardinal functions

For the countably infinite case, consider defining
$$
x_n := \frac{1}{2^n}, \qquad n=0,1,2,\cdots
$$
to be the "edges" of the open intervals, and then
$$
m_n := \frac{x_n + x_{n+1}}{2}, \qquad n = 1,2,3,\cdots
$$
to be their midpoints. Notice that $(x_{n+1},x_n)$ has width
$$
x_n-x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2^n} - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}
$$
So we will choose our radius as half that,
$$
r_n := \frac{1}{2^{n+2}}
$$
and then
$$
\left\{ \left( m_n - r_n, m_n + r_n \right) \right\}_{n=1}^\infty
$$
is a collection of countably many intervals, diskoint and within $(0,1)$.
You can see it more visually in this Desmos demo. Below, I've highlighted alternating intervals per the parity of their $n$:


To see that you can't have uncountably many, consider:
If $\{S_i\}_{i \in I}$ are such that

$S_i \subseteq (0,1)$ for each $i$
the $S_i$ are disjoint
the $S_i$ are intervals

then the following are true:

each $S_i$ has a positive length, i.e. $\operatorname{length}(S_i) > 0$ for each $i$
$\sum \operatorname{length}(S_i) \le \operatorname{length}((0,1))=1$

Can the latter ever be achieved for an uncountable set?

Sorry what do you mean by the last question ?

Sum of the lengths of uncountable collection of disjoint open subintervals is always greater than 1?

Yup. More generally, any uncountable sum of positive numbers is infinite

The set of (left) endpoints can have a limit point in the closed interval $[0,1]$ that is not part of, or an end point of, any of the individual open subintervals. A simple example is the set of subintervals $(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n)$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$

So that kinda discard both my assumptions. Oops I cant vote up
